# Generating sequence from Markov chain in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I would like to generate random sequences from a Markov chain. To generate the Markov chain I use the following code.

```
module Main where

import qualified Control.Monad.Random as R
import qualified Data.List as L
import qualified Data.Map as M

type TransitionMap = M.Map (String, String) Int
type MarkovChain = M.Map String [(String, Int)]

addTransition :: (String, String) -> TransitionMap -> TransitionMap
addTransition k = M.insertWith (+) k 1

fromTransitionMap :: TransitionMap -> MarkovChain
fromTransitionMap m =
  M.fromList [(k, frequencies k) | k <- ks]
  where ks = L.nub $ map fst $ M.keys m
        frequencies a = map reduce $ filter (outboundFor a) $ M.toList m
        outboundFor a k = fst (fst k) == a
        reduce e = (snd (fst e), snd e)
```

After collecting the statistics and generating a Markov Chain object I would like to generate random sequences. I could imagine this method could look something like that (pseudo-code)

```
generateSequence mc s
  | s == "." = s
  | otherwise = s ++ " " ++ generateSequence mc s'
  where s' = drawRandomlyFrom $ R.fromList $ mc ! s
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain to me, how I should implement this function.

**Edit**

If anyone's interested it wasn't as difficult as I thought.

```
module Main where

import qualified Control.Monad.Random as R
import qualified Data.List as L
import qualified Data.Map as M

type TransitionMap = M.Map (String, String) Rational
type MarkovChain = M.Map String [(String, Rational)]

addTransition :: TransitionMap -> (String, String) -> TransitionMap
addTransition m k = M.insertWith (+) k 1 m

fromTransitionMap :: TransitionMap -> MarkovChain
fromTransitionMap m =
  M.fromList [(k, frequencies k) | k <- ks]
  where ks = L.nub $ map fst $ M.keys m
        frequencies a = map reduce $ filter (outboundFor a) $ M.toList m
        outboundFor a k = fst (fst k) == a
        reduce e = (snd (fst e), snd e)

generateSequence :: (R.MonadRandom m) => MarkovChain -> String -> m String
generateSequence m s
  | not (null s) && last s == '.' = return s
  | otherwise = do
                s' <- R.fromList $ m M.! s
                ss <- generateSequence m s'
                return $ if null s then ss else s ++ " " ++ ss

fromSample :: [String] -> MarkovChain
fromSample ss = fromTransitionMap $ foldl addTransition M.empty $ concatMap pairs ss
  where pairs s = let ws = words s in zipWith (,) ("":ws) ws

sample :: [String]
sample = [ "I am a monster."
         , "I am a rock star."
         , "I want to go to Hawaii."
         , "I want to eat a hamburger."
         , "I have a really big headache."
         , "Haskell  is a fun language."
         , "Go eat a big hamburger."
         , "Markov chains are fun to use."
         ]

main = do
  s <- generateSequence (fromSample sample) ""
  print s
```

The only tiny annoyance is the fake `""` starting node.

Comment: if `generateSequence` is to be run in `MonadRandom`, you'd need `return`s there.

Comment: do you care to elaborate please? I'm not that experiences in the whole monad thing. I do understand enough, to see that ++ not gonna work if I try to concatenate a `String` and `Monad m => m a`. Second I'm not sure how `drawRandomlyFrom` function should look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for. This compiles though:

```
generateSequence :: (R.MonadRandom m) => MarkovChain -> String -> m String
generateSequence mc s  | s == "." = return s
                       | otherwise = do  
                            s' <- R.fromList $ rationalize (mc M.! s)
                            s'' <- generateSequence mc s'
                            return $ s ++ " " ++ s'' 

rationalize :: [(String,Int)] -> [(String,Rational)]
rationalize = map  (\(x,i) -> (x, toRational i))
```

Answer (score 1):

All random number generation needs to happen in either the `Random` monad or the `IO` monad. For your purpose, it's probably easiest to understand how to do that in the `IO` monad, using `evalRandIO`. In the example below, `getRandom` is the function we want to use. Now `getRandom` operates in the `Random` monad, but we can use `evalRandIO` to lift it to the `IO` monad, like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  x <- evalRandIO getRandom :: IO Double
  putStrLn $ "Your random number is " ++ show x
```

Note: The reason we have to add the type signature to the line that binds x is because in this particular example there are no other hints to tell the compiler what type we want `x` to be. However, if we used `x` in some way that makes it clear that we want it to be a `Double` (e.g., multiplying by another `Double`), then the type signature wouldn't be necessary.

Using your `MarkovChain` type, for a current state you can trivially get the available transitions in the form `[(`*nextState*`,`*probability*`)]`. (I'm using the word "probability" loosely, it doesn't need to be a true probability; any numeric weight is fine). This is what `fromList` in `Control.Monad.Random` is designed for. Again, it operates in the `Random` monad, but we can use `evalRandIO` to lift it to the `IO` monad. Suppose `transitions` is your list of transitions, having the type `[(`*nextState*`,`*probability*`)]`. Then, in the IO monad you can call:

```
nextState <- evalRandIO $ fromList transitions
```

You might instead want to create your own function that operates in the `Random` monad, like this:

```
getRandomTransition :: RandomGen g => MarkovChain -> String -> Rand g String
getRandomTransition currState chain = do
    let transitions = lookup currState chain
    fromList transitions
```

Then you can call this function in the `IO` monad using `evalRandIO`, e.g.

```
nextState <- evalRandIO $ getRandomTransition chain
```